# How to create a span element in bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a table with a number of visitors. To sum all the visitors, i use some javascript.
The sum of all the visitors should be injected in `<span class="totalvisitors"></span>`.
This works fine when putting the span under the table. But i want to create the span inside the title of the tooltip inside the `th`. Problem: it shows literally the `<span class="totalvisitors"></span>` inside the tooltip without the number of visitors.

My tooltip looks like this:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th scope="col" tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-html="true" title='Total Visitors:<span class="totalvisitors"></span>'>Visitors</th>
      
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Here you can see the issue in a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z21q9wo8/2/) (hover over Visitors)

Answer (score 0):

You are using bootstrap 4, where there are different attributes with previous versions of bootstrap which uses `data-bs-html="true"` while in bootstrap 4 it uses `data-html="true"`

So your code must be

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th scope="col" tabindex="0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title='Total Visitors:<span class="totalvisitors"></span>'>Visitors</th>
    </tr> 
</thead>
```